# running a JScript file in cmd.exe by a button

Tags: c#, visual-studio, button

I have a button in my form that when its clicked, it will open command prompt and automatically run a javascript file. My code so far only opens the command prompt. How do you run a javascript file?

```
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe";
        process.Start();
```

Comment: Run JavaScript in Windows: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12058548/run-javascript-in-windows

Comment: Do you actually want the command prompt? or would launching the .js script directly work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that we know that you're trying to launch a Node.js app, try this new version.
And don't forget that C# is pretty well documented [on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments(v=vs.110).aspx).

If the rest of your code is working as is, and you don't actually want/need to run CMD.exe, this should do the trick:

```
    Process process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe";
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"P:\ath\To\Your\File.js";
    process.Start();
```

As a holdover from the original question: If you had been trying to launch a JScript script, you would want to use `@"C:\Windows\System32\Cscript.exe"`, or if you want to launch a JScript script without seeing a command prompt window, replace `Cscript` with `Wscript`.

Comment: I used your code and it works but it gives me Mircosoft JScript runtime error. Why does it so?

Comment: i found out the file that I want to open is a JScript script file not a JavaScript file, my bad. When i open through Cscript.exe, it did not work as it throw the same error. How do i open JScript file then? My bad.

Comment: JavaScript and JScript are both implementations of ECMAscript. JScript is made by Microsoft. If your script is JScript, meant to be run directly on windows (i.e. not in a browser), then Cscript or Wscript should work. So I guess what I should ask is, what do you get if you run the `.js` file by double-clicking on it?

Comment: it gets the same error which was the Microsoft JScript Runtime error when i double-click on it

Comment: but i can open the JScript file through cmd.exe where I have to put node myfile.js to work. How is that so?

Comment: Ah! Then this isn't about a Jscript file. It's about launching a node app. Is that it?

Comment: ah yes my bad. Im utterly confused about this JScript and Javascript. I need to type in node myfile.js to work on my cmd.exe.

Comment: ah thank you so much for your wonderful help. Gladly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe";
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.Start();

process.StandardInput.WriteLine("Cscript.exe \"PathToYourFile\\file.js\"");
//OR
//process.StandardInput.WriteLine("Wscript.exe \"PathToYourFile\\file.js\"");
process.StandardInput.Flush();
process.StandardInput.Close();
```

Comment: This might help too: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yeah, guess it depends if he wants to see output to the command window or not. If I didn't need the command window I would be using the executable directly too maybe he doesn't need it.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Gladly appreciated! @Xela